# Facebook PHP SDK send apprequests

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK and I'm trying to send an apprequests.

This is my code :

```
    $fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'app_id',
      'app_secret' => 'secret',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($request->get('token'));

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);

    $request = $fb->request('POST', '/me/apprequests', 
     array ('message' => 'This is a test message','to' => '10156388930270332')); 
     //10156388930270332 is my facebook id

    // Send the request to Graph
    try {
      $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
```

With this code, I have no error. If I check the `$response`, I have a statut 200 (OK), I can see my message, the `to` parameter but I don't get any notification on my account...

What I missed ?

Comment: did you only check on mobile or on desktop too?

Comment: Is the app possibly in development mode and you are sending the request to a non Admin or Developer of the app? This would probably cause this to happen.